# Is Button's background colored by colorPrimary, not colorAccent?

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android

My Settings: minSdkVersion 19 && compileSdkVersion 30

I tried below code. I expected the button's background to be colored as `colorAccent`, but it was colored as `colorPrimary`. When I change `colorPrimary` value to another color, the button's background color changes accordingly.

This is contrary to what I learned. (Button's background should be colored by `colorAccent` when style is "@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"). I encountered this problem while following the Google Android fundamental tutorial (https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interactivity/index.html#4).

I am getting confused, please help.

```xml
// activity_main.xml
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:id="@+id/done_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/done" />

// themes.xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AboutMe" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>

// colors.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#880000</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a Material Components Theme, your `Button` is replaced at runtime by a `MaterialButton`.

The [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md) uses as background tint the `?attr/colorPrimary`.
The style `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` applies a background drawable which is overridden by the `MaterialShapeDrawable` provided by the `MaterialButton`.

Use a Material Components style in your `Button` as **`Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`** and the **`app:backgroundTint`** to apply a different color in your background:

```
   <Button
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/....."
    ../>
```

or:

```
  <Button
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonThemeOverlayPrimaryColor"
    ../>


  <style name="ButtonThemeOverlayPrimaryColor">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

or if you want to use an `AppCompat` style use a `AppCompatButton`.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that too button color set default as primary instead of Accent color but
You can fix it by setting android:backgroundTint attribute of button instead of style-

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Button"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint`.

Comment: No. Using a Material Components Theme the Button is replaced by a MaterialButton, and the right attribute is app:backgroundTint.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was also helpful.